# iOS/Swift App delegate code not being run first

Tags: ios, swift, appdelegate

In my application: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method, I set some non-optional dictionaries and save them to the standard user defaults. However, the dictionaries are not available when the tableview loads, and my app breaks down.

Also, I have a println(1) that does not get run in the application: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method before the tableView is loaded and the app crashes.

I am just wondering when the application: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: is run relative to when the first view is initialized.

Comment: Are you sure that you saved those dictionaries correctly to the user defaults? Did you valled synchronize after you set the values of the user defaults? Otherwise, they has to be set when the views appear, unless you set these things on a delayed background thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

application: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: gets called first.  It seems as though you save dictionaries in defaults and then try to read them very soon after.  If you read the docs for NSUserDefaults, it is not guaranteed that the defaults have saved when you set objects, for efficiency purposes.  You should call defaults.synchronize() to ensure that they save after you set the dictionaries if you plan on relying on them to save right when you set them.

Comment: @Nico Yes, but my answer was in the context of the question being asked.  "I am just wondering when the application: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: is run relative to when the first view is initialized."  Relative to the first view being initialized didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: is first.  Hope that clears up the confusion for you.